# Execute a batch file before executing in a shortcut (.lnk)

Tags: windows, batch-file, lnk

I have multiple versions of a program called Siemens NX. NX uses environmental variables for configuration. I need NX 10.0 to use a different set of environmental variables than my NX 7.5 which uses the system environmental variables. Therefore, I have written a batch file that setups the environmental variables that I need. However, There is a lot of different programs that go with NX 10.0. I don't want to have to create a batch file for each program. Instead, I just want to ammend the shortcuts (.lnk) to execute a batch file before starting. For instance, this is easily done by

```
C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\setup_NX10_environment.bat && C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\ugraf.exe -nx
```

However, the command window is left open. How can I call the batch script and it closes and then calls my program?

Comment: Did you tried like this ==> C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\setup_NX10_environment.bat && C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\ugraf.exe -nx & Exit

Comment: I just tried that and it does not work. Note that you only used one "&". shortcuts (.lnk) require two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply program with parameters to your batch script as follows

```
C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\setup_NX10_environment.bat "C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\ugraf.exe" -nx
```

and improve that batch as follows:

```
rem all the original setup_NX10_environment.bat stuff here
%*
exit
```

or

```
rem all the original setup_NX10_environment.bat stuff here
call %*
exit
```

or

```
rem all the original setup_NX10_environment.bat stuff here
start "" %*
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The console window may remain open if you call the executable like this:

```
executable.exe
```

However, prepending `start` to the executable will detach it from the console. 
Thus the console will not remain open if you call the executable like this:

```
start executable.exe
```

In conclusion, rewrite your command as follows:

```
C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\setup_NX10_environment.bat && start C:\Siemens\NX10\UGII\ugraf.exe -nx
```

Comment: Good thought. I have tried it. It does not work inside a shortcut (.lnk)